# Syntax error simple python program confused

Tags: python

I am new to python working on codecademy. I writing a program for calculating shipping costs. Could someone tell me what is wrong with this syntax? Much appreciated.

```
weight = 8

#Ground Shipping
if weight <= 2:
  print("""Price per Pound: $1.50
Flat Charge:     $20.00""")
cost_ground = weight * 1.5 +20

elif weight > 2 and <= 6:
  print("""Price per Pound: $3.00
Flat Charge:     $20.00""")
cost_ground = weight * 3 +20

elif weight > 6 and <= 10:
  print("""Price per Pound: $4.00
Flat Charge:     $20.00""")
cost_ground = weight * 4 +20

else weight > 10:
  print("""Price per Pound: $4.75
Flat Charge:     $20.00""")
cost_ground = weight * 4.75 +20
```

ERROR:

```
File "shipping.py", line 8
    elif weight > 2 and <= 6:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want this file to print correctly if I change the weight but I am stuck on this error.

Comment: It's probably your indentation (or lack of it)

Comment: `elif weight > 2 and <= 6:` would need to be `elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:`, and you need to fix your indentation.

Comment: `cost_ground = weight * 1.5 +20` isn't indented, so that means the `if` was terminated, then the `elif` is a syntax error because there is no `if` for it to match with.

Comment: @AKX FWIW, `weight > 2 and weight <= 6` can be simplified to `2 < weight <= 6`

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I know. As explained in my answer, the other bound is unnecessary since we're in an if/elif chain.

Answer (score 0):

`cost_ground = weight * 1.5 +20` line after the first `if` statement is not indented. That ends the `if` statement and `elif` cannot be used outside an if statement. Actually all such lines are not indented, so all the following `elif` statements will fail.

Answer (score 0):

- Your indentation is incorrect.
- `elif weight > 2 and <= 6:` (etc.) would need to be `elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6:`, but the second condition isn't really needed since the previous branches will have taken care of that.

This simplifies to something like

```
weight = 8

if weight <= 2:
    price_per_pound = 1.5
    flat_charge = 20.00
elif weight <= 6:
    price_per_pound = 3.00
    flat_charge = 20.00
elif weight <= 10:
    price_per_pound = 4.00
    flat_charge = 20.00
else:
    price_per_pound = 4.75
    flat_charge = 20.00

cost_ground = weight * price_per_pound + flat_charge

print(f"Price per Pound: ${price_per_pound}")
print(f"Flat Charge:     ${flat_charge}")
print(f"Total Cost:      ${cost_ground}")
```

(and of course since `flat_charge` is always the same here, you could get rid of that in the `if` branches and just set it beforehand.)